# Split a Javascript string of dates and group them by year

Tags: javascript

Start string

```
let current dates'01/02/2021,09/08/2021,11/22/2021,11/23/2021,12/24/2021,01/02/2022,01/03/2022,09/08/2023,11/22/2024,11/23/2022,12/24/2023,01/02/2025,01/03/2026,09/08/2027'
```

I need to convert to and array of strings sorted by year:

```
let closureDates = ['01/02/2021,09/08/2021,11/22/2021,11/23/2021,12/24/2021','01/02/2022,01/03/2022,11/23/2022','09/08/2023,12/24/2023','11/22/2024','01/02/2025','01/03/2026','09/08/2027',
```

```
destructClosureDates(closureDatesMultpleYrs)

function destructClosureDates(dates) {
    let strDates = dates.split(",")
    let strDays = []
    let strYears = []
    strDates.forEach(day => {
        strDays.push(day.split('/'))
    })
    strDays.forEach(day => {
        strYears.push(day[2])
    })

    let sortedDates = strDates.sort((a, b) => {
        a = a.split('/')
        b = b.split('/')

        return a[2].localeCompare(b[2]);
    })

    let unqiYears = [...new Set(strYears)]
    let sortedUniYears = unqiYears.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.localeCompare(b)
    })
}

    const Lmap = new Map(Object.entries(newArr));
```

I'm not sure how to loop through the Map and combine the dates strings by year. Do I need to restructure the code in another data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call accumulating into an object using the year as key. This allows you to avoid an explicit `sort()` call by leveraging the fact that integer object properties are implicitly sorted (see: [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)).

```js
const
  currentDates = '09/08/2027,01/02/2021,09/08/2021,11/22/2021,11/23/2021,12/24/2021,01/02/2022,01/03/2022,09/08/2023,11/22/2024,11/23/2022,12/24/2023,01/02/2025,01/03/2026',

  closureDates = Object
    .values(
      currentDates
        .split(',')
        .reduce((a, date) => {
          const [, , year] = date.split('/');
          a[year] = (year in a) ? `${a[year]},${date}` : date;
          return a;
        }, {})
    );

console.log(closureDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split to each date by "," then sort it by split date by "/" take last value and sort by it then just join it.

```js
const dates = '01/02/2021,09/08/2021,11/22/2021,11/23/2021,12/24/2021,01/02/2022,01/03/2022,09/08/2023,11/22/2024,11/23/2022,12/24/2023,01/02/2025,01/03/2026,09/08/2027'

const sorted = dates
  .split(",")
  .sort((a,b) => +a.split("/")[2] - +b.split("/")[2])
  .join(",")

console.log(sorted)
```

or comparing full date object (sorted decreasing)

```js
const dates = '01/02/2021,09/08/2021,11/22/2021,11/23/2021,12/24/2021,01/02/2022,01/03/2022,09/08/2023,11/22/2024,11/23/2022,12/24/2023,01/02/2025,01/03/2026,09/08/2027'

const sorted = dates
  .split(",")
  .sort((a,b) => new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime())
  .join(",")

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` to create an array of text dates.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Then using `Array.sort()`, you can just convert the dates from text to a `new Date()` for the sorting purpose.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

**Bonus**

You can also use `Array.filter()` to pull out any specific value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

See snippet where the descending array is also filtered on the year 2021.

```js
const currentdates = `01/02/2021,09/08/2021,11/22/2021,11/23/2021,12/24/2021,01/02/2022,01/03/2022,09/08/2023,11/22/2024,11/23/2022,12/24/2023,01/02/2025,01/03/2026,09/08/2027`;

const sortedAsc = [currentdates
  .split(`,`)
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b))
  .join(`,`)
];

const sortedDesc = [currentdates
  .split(`,`)
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(b) - new Date(a))
  .filter(elem => new Date(elem).getFullYear() == 2021)
  .join(`,`)
];



document.write("<h4>Ascending:</h4><br><code>");
document.write(JSON.stringify(sortedAsc, null, 2));

document.write("</code><br><br><h4>Descending and Filtered on the year 2021:</h4><br><code>");
document.write(JSON.stringify(sortedDesc, null, 2));
document.write("</code>");
```

**EDIT**

I just read your post again and realized that I didn't scroll your intended results to see that you would like an array with the dates as strings grouped by years.

After creating the array of dates, using the `Array.reduce()` method, you can grab the year from each date using `new Date(elem).getFullYear()`, and add them to a `new Set()`. Since a `Set` won't allow duplicates, you get a unique list of years.

You can then use `Set.forEach()` to loop through all of the years and filter the `dateArray` by each year, and use `Array.join()` on the filtered array to create a string of dates. You can then `Array.push()` the filtered array to the `closureDates` array.

updated snippet below:

```js
const currentdates = `01/02/2021,09/08/2021,11/22/2021,11/23/2021,12/24/2021,01/02/2022,01/03/2022,09/08/2023,11/22/2024,11/23/2022,12/24/2023,01/02/2025,01/03/2026,09/08/2027`;

const closureDates = [];

const dateArray = currentdates.split(`,`);
const years = dateArray.reduce((a, c) => a.add(new Date(c).getFullYear()), new Set);

years.forEach( y => {
  const filtered = dateArray.filter( el => new Date(el).getFullYear() === y).join(`,`);
  closureDates.push(filtered);
});

document.write(`<pre>${JSON.stringify(closureDates, null, 2)}</pre>`);
```